# Acces to method with array from another class

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to get value from method getLiczbe from the class Losujliczbe to the class Main. The compiler says by class Main "Multiple markers at this line- getLiczbe cannot be resolved to a type".

The target was to get the value of the method getLiczbe (random number) and put this into JavaFX button in class Main. 
It has good worked if I had no array in the class. After converting to array it does not work...

Could somebody help me with this code? Thank you very much!

```
*************************************************
Class Losujliczbe with the method getLiczbe:

package application;
//import java.util.Random;

public class Losujliczbe {

    private int zmienna;


    // Method for obtain a number between [0 - 49].

    public Losujliczbe(int z) {         
        this.zmienna=z;
    }

    public static int[] getLiczbe() {
        for(int i=0;i<=0;i++) {
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
           int[]arr=new int[1];
           arr[i]=random;                           
         }
        return getLiczbe();
    }
}

*************************************************
```

Short code of the Class Main with the compiler failure:

```
   getLiczbe br=new getLiczbe();
   String str1=String.valueOf(br.getLiczbe());

   Button btn = new Button(str1);
   grid.add(btn,0,4);
```

Comment: `int[] values = Losujliczbe.getLiczbe();` Method is static so you don't need an instance. See further issue in comment below however.

Comment: Pretty sure that the `getLiczbe` method will throw a StackOverflowException when called, since it is calling itself.

Comment: Also using an int array in `String.valueOf` will give the reference to the array - something like `[I@7a79be86`

Comment: There are a few issues here as highlighted above. getLiczbe is not a type but a static method hence your error "getLiczbe cannot be resolved to a type". getLiczbe also returns a call to getLiczbe which will lead to an infinite span of calls and then a StackOverflow exception.

Comment: Replace getLiczbe br=new getLiczbe(); with int[] br = Losujliczbe.getLiczbe();. I think you are confused with static functions and how object oriented programming works, check out https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/oo-140949.html

Comment: The whole function is odd. Why a single element array? Why a one iteration loop. Could just be `public static int getLiczbe() { return (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);`}

Comment: It's array beacause there will be more buttons later. I just wanted to test it for the 1 array. And yes there is StackOverflowException now after changing to int[] values = Losujliczbe.getLiczbe()....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you changed your code to get array. Here is the working code for array.

Make your changes as per your requirement.

```
public class Losujliczbe {

    private int zmienna;

    // Method for obtain a number between [0 - 49].

    public Losujliczbe(int z) {         
        this.zmienna=z;
    }

    public int[] getLiczbe() {
        int arr[] = new int[zmienna];
        for(int i=0; i < zmienna; i++) {
            int random = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
            arr[i]=random;                           
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Losujliczbe br = new Losujliczbe(3); // 3 or any number for the default arg constructor
        int[] arr = br.getLiczbe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you solokiran, now it's working fine! Of course as already Rashin mentioned, now the "String.valueOf" from array shows the reference to the array ;-)

Comment: Alreaddy solved with: Losujliczbe br=new Losujliczbe(3);
       int[] arr = br.getLiczbe();
       String str1=Arrays.toString(arr);                                                                         Now the button shows the whole array (like 40,0,0) but anyway thank you all again. You have saved me a lot of time!